# Fast real-time plotting software in python

Tags: python, programming, graphs, real-time, plotting

I'm currently using matplotlib to do real-time scatter plotting, but it's way too slow. I'm getting ~7 frames per second, and I'm looking to get ~250 frames per second. Each frame would consist of around 1000 points.

The only functionality that I'm looking for is to be able to load data from multiple files and to be able to scatter plot them continuously with a frame rate of ~250 fps. It would also be nice to have the ability to pause the simulation, rewind, fast forward, and restart.

Is there any practical software that would allow me to achieve this goal?

Comment: matplotlib has tons of features, which ones do you use? We can't help you without this information. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Thanks for your suggestion! I edited my post to reflect your advice.

Comment: What are you viewing thes 250 frames per second on? (Most monitors refreshrates cap out way below that, and when FPS>Refresh rate then you will see nothing.).

Comment: You did not mention _how_ you use matplotlib, so if you `clear()` your figure between every frame the simulation runs much slower than if you just update the figure. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098131/how-to-update-a-plot-in-matplotlib for more details.